# How to close the tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to close the current window 2 seconds after it appears

if you insert time.sleep(2) before win.mainloop(), the window will not be displayed for 2 seconds, and I need it to open and close after 2 seconds

```
    global win
    win = Tk()

    win.attributes('-alpha', 0.0)
    win.iconify()

    window = Toplevel(win)
    window.geometry("300x300+" + str(randint(0, 1400)) + "+" + str(randint(0, 700)))
    window.overrideredirect(1)

    photo = PhotoImage(file="classes/bin/starters/spaceStorage/popUps/" + rand + r".png")

    label = Label(window, image=photo)
    label.pack()

    win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.after()` instead of `time.sleep()`:

```py
...
# destroy root window after 2 seconds
win.after(2000, win.destroy)
win.mainloop()
```

Why don't you just use the root window instead of hiding it and create another toplevel?